# Is there any way to detect edge in this situation?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

I try to detect edge using python.
There are hundreds of algorithms for edge detection, however, the image is very obscure and unclear. The most serious problem is one edge is located at the local maximum value, but the other edge is located slightly shifted from local maximum value. Through the detailed examination, I found the other edge is located at the one of the inflection points of original values. I depicted this situation as a simple situation.

Is there any simple and beautiful ways for detection edges in various situations?

[image]

Comment: From this one example graph, the answer is very simple: take the maximum of the image value and the minimum of the derivative. But that's probably too specific for your actual situation. You will need to provide more details and some example images if you want a useful answer.

Comment: (By the way, I don't understand how the plot relates to the original image. Is it a histogram of sorts?)

Comment: This is more two nearby ridges than a single edge. And a grayscale maximum does not correspond to an edge, so I disagree with your left edge ! In fact, in this case you might consider 2, 3 or 4 edges.

Comment: looks like you have some shift. If I understand correctly, `Real edge` are labels which you want to get but you do not know how. if both real edges were shifted to the left, you could define the edge as "were signal starts to drop from big values to small values". Without this "fix" of labels I see no possibility to make a defintion of edge that makes sense and fits this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no simple and beautiful method to detect edges. This is an ill-posed problem. In particular, there is no absolute criterion to tell signal from noise.

A not-so-bad method is to consider the peaks of the derivative, provided they correspond to a sufficiently high step in the signal.

[image]